# String value null after call another method android java

Tags: java, android, firebase

**private variable audioLink** null after call another method like **setAudio()** even it is also null outside **onComplete Method**.I tired to solve this.

```
private String audioLink;

private void setData() {
        //FireBase Get Details Section
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore.collection("SUBJECT")
                .document(subjectName).collection("CHAPTER")
                .document(chapterName.toUpperCase())
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        txtDetails.setText(document.get("chapterDetails").toString());
                        audioLink = document.get("audioLink").toString();//Assigning Value
                    } else {
                        txtDetails.setText("Empty");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("Error", "Cached get failed: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
    }

private void setAudio() {
        try {
            String url = audioLink; // your URL here
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: from where you calling setAudio method?

Comment: in the same class

Comment: audioLink = document.get("audioLink").toString();//Assigning Value

First, debug that you're getting the value of this `document.get("audioLink").toString();//Assigning Value`  here might be getting null. 

If you're getting value then try making static audioLink `private static String audioLink;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call it  inside onComplete method:

```
private String audioLink;

private void setData() {
    //FireBase Get Details Section
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firebaseFirestore.collection("SUBJECT")
            .document(subjectName).collection("CHAPTER")
            .document(chapterName.toUpperCase())
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    txtDetails.setText(document.get("chapterDetails").toString());
                    audioLink = document.get("audioLink").toString();//Assigning Value
                 setAudio(); // you need to call if from here 
                } else {
                    txtDetails.setText("Empty");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("Error", "Cached get failed: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i do multiple task through audioLink

Comment: Ok but you will only get audio link after onComplete method finished as it is background task.

Comment: yes of-cause but sorry i am not understand background task.

Comment: as audio link you are getting from firestore and it will take some time to get response and if you are not calling your method from onComplete then it will first call setAudio method and then after you will get audio link from firestore so that you are getting null value. You may check this thing by putting logs or using debugging your code.